# What does the instructions sequence call/cdqe/ret do?

Tags: kernel, assembly

I'm trying to reverse a Linux module. In the `ioctl` routine, I have the following sequence of instructions (generated by `objdump -M intel -d test.ko`):

```
 3f9:   74 3b                   je     436 <device_ioctl+0x46>
...
 436:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   43b <device_ioctl+0x4b>
 43b:   48 98                   cdqe   
 43d:   c3                      ret
```

I'm not sure to understand what happens here after the jump is done.

First, we have a [`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) instruction. The opcode is `E8 00` so it is a near call to the next instruction. The EIP register (which contain the address of the next instruction) is also pushed on the stack.

Then, we continue with the [`cdqe`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cbw:cwde:cdqe) instruction. It extends the sign of the EAX register into RAX. In other words, it does nothing. Just to mention, EAX/RAX register has not been modified from the beginning of the routine.

Finally, the [`ret`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) instruction is executed. It pops the stack into EIP which corresponds to the previous instruction and we continue the execution of the routine from that point.

Therefore, `cdqe` is executed again (to do nothing) and the `ret` instruction is called again. This time, we leave the `ioctl` routine and return to the callee.

Am I right saying this does nothing? If so, what is the point of that code?

---

Here is the full routine:

```
00000000000003f0 <device_ioctl>:
 3f0:   48 89 d7                mov    rdi,rdx
 3f3:   81 fe 03 b0 fe ca       cmp    esi,0xcafeb003
 3f9:   74 3b                   je     436 <device_ioctl+0x46>
 3fb:   77 18                   ja     415 <device_ioctl+0x25>
 3fd:   81 fe 01 b0 fe ca       cmp    esi,0xcafeb001
 403:   74 39                   je     43e <device_ioctl+0x4e>
 405:   81 fe 02 b0 fe ca       cmp    esi,0xcafeb002
 40b:   75 39                   jne    446 <device_ioctl+0x56>
 40d:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   412 <device_ioctl+0x22>
 412:   48 98                   cdqe   
 414:   c3                      ret    
 415:   48 c7 c0 00 00 00 00    mov    rax,0x0
 41c:   48 c7 c2 ff ff ff ff    mov    rdx,0xffffffffffffffff
 423:   48 2d 00 00 00 00       sub    rax,0x0
 429:   81 fe 04 b0 fe ca       cmp    esi,0xcafeb004
 42f:   89 c0                   mov    eax,eax
 431:   48 0f 45 c2             cmovne rax,rdx
 435:   c3                      ret    
 436:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   43b <device_ioctl+0x4b>
 43b:   48 98                   cdqe   
 43d:   c3                      ret    
 43e:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   443 <device_ioctl+0x53>
 443:   48 98                   cdqe   
 445:   c3                      ret    
 446:   48 83 c8 ff             or     rax,0xffffffffffffffff
 44a:   c3                      ret
```

This is from the nightclub challenge of the [pbctf 2021](https://ctf.perfect.blue/).

---

Answer (score 1):

cdqe does this RAX ← sign-extend of EAX.
applicable only in x64
shown below is a demo of x86 cdq which instead of using rax uses eax,edx combo
edx gets the sign extension  in x86

for cdqe register rax will become `0xffffffff<eax> or 0x00000000<eax>`

[image]

maybe ctf is checking the sign